# jquery validation engine date picker customization & localization

Tags: jquery, validation, date, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jquery validation engine in my php reservation (booking) form.
I want to change the date format as DD/MM/YYYY. and also change the month names in other languages.

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add some code. it would be better to give answer.

Comment: <label>
    <span>Check-In Date : </span>
    <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input datepicker" type="text" name="CIDate" id="CIDate" />
   </label>

   <label>
    <span>Check-Out Date : </span>
    <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input datepicker" type="text" name="CODate" id="CODate" />
   </label>

my form: http://www.logelato.com/Elkep/Booking-EN.html

Comment: are you using jquery datepicker?

Comment: yes. jquery datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change format of date use dateFormat as below:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'
});
```

[JQuery UI Datepicker Docs](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

Comment: that worked thank you. and do you know about localization/globalization?

Comment: yes but not getting your question about localization. where you wanna show?